# Why does French use definite plural articles when the meaning is indefinite?

Tags: articles, articles-definis

Google translate says that "The team solves operational problems" translates into "L'équipe résout les problèmes opérationnels".  It is impossible a single team to be able to solve *all* such problems, as the required areas of expertise is too broad.  It seems that the indefinite article should be used, i.e., des problèmes opérationnels.  French seems to routinely use definite article (plural) when the intended meaning is in English requires an indefinite article.  Can some one please explain the reason?

The context of this question is to do French homework describing one's work.  The same question could be asked about "algorithmic problems" instead of the "operational problems" above.  Basically, a large class of problems of which a small team of people can only realistically have expertise in small subset.

Comment: You shouldn't postulate Google translate is always right but in that case, I'm not even able to tell if *des* or *les* would be the best article to use to translate your sentence, given the fact you provide zero context. What is that team? What kind of problems does it solves? Is this sentence a reply to a question (in such case what question?) or is it a statement presenting the role of the team?

Comment: Thanks for the prompting.  I added some context.  Please let me know if you think it would help for me to elaborate on any particular aspect.  P.S. It's not just Google translation of this one phrase.  I see this a lot, and have never actually posed the question.

Comment: You misunderstood my last question. I was asking if *The team solves operational problems* is the reply to a question or just a statement. Anyway, if you see this a lot, give examples where you found *les* used in French where no article would have been used in English.

Comment: It's a statement, as I am describing a job, which is part of a team that solves problems of a certain broad type.  I have seen it a lot over the years, but haven't noted where.  I can't find examples from Google translate, at least for now, other than the above, and "I like apples" ("J'aime les pommes").  But I suppose that the latter could mean *all* apples, or a particular batch of apples.

Comment: It could be helpful if you would provide us with your source indicating that "les" means "all the" (I can somewhat undrestand the idea).

Comment: This was from a course many years ago.  I believe that the explanation was that "les" refers to a class of things, like "apples", rather than a specific collection of apples.  I'm recalling this from memory.

Comment: How can a plural definite article in French mean something **indefinite**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning is not indefinite but *generic*, and in English the use of  the zero article is the norm in generic determination whereas in French what is used is the articles "le", "la" and "les", which are used also as definite determiners.

- Cigarettes are bad for your health.
  ***Les** cigarettes sont dangereuses pour la santé.*
- Research shows that it is the elderly who are the prime victims of inflation.
  ***Les** recherches montrent que ce sont les personnes agées qui sont les victimes principales de **l**'inflation.*

Comment: Thanks, I found more here: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/definite-article

Comment: So glad to see a simple, accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

When generically describing a job, the plural definite article might be used in French where English would use no article:

*Le pompier éteint les incendies

Le garagiste répare les voitures

Le docteur soigne les malades

Le policier arrête les voleurs

Le dentiste arrache les dents...*

That doesn't imply all thieves are arrested or all teeth are pulled out...

Comment: Thanks, I found a description here: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/definite-article